# Detect route leave in component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Vue router has really useful in-component guard `beforeRouteLeave`, which is, quoting: "called when the route that renders this component is about to be navigated away from. Has access to this component instance".

Is there something similar in Angular? In short, I'm looking for method, which would be called in component, when user is leaving from it because of route change.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the angular/routing module

```html
import { NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {
        router.events.subscribe(
            (event) => {
                if ( event instanceof NavigationStart ) {
                    // Handle Navigation Start
                }

                if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
                    // Handle Navigation End
                }
            });
    }
```

SIDENOTE: You can look into Ionic if you want to take control of the life cycle hooks it uses. They are a little more intuitive than Angular's core life cycle hooks. 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: Thanks! With some extra checks, I could use that method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ngOnDestroy()` Lifecycle hook to check if the user has exited a view it can be found here -> https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Thanks, this would be good solution for lot of cases, but my component won't be destroyed.

Answer (score -1):

If you using the method `navigateByUrl` or `navigate` of `Router` then before calling this method, you can perform the required task.

*For example*,

```
     someMethod(){
        ....
        ....
        //desired functionality
        this.rouer.navigateByUrl(some path);
     }
```